# NoMethodError in Rails 2.3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this strange error in one of my rails 2.3.2 application.

```
NoMethodError in Timesheet#index 

undefined method '>=' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #27):

24:       for alog in act_logs
25:         if alog.user_id == session[:user_id].id
27:           if(alog.log_date>=@dt.beginning_of_week()&&  alog.log_date<=@dt.end_of_week())
```

As far as I can guess, I think either `alog.log_date` or `@dt.beginning_of_week` is nil. But a quick inspection just before line #27(inspection not included here) shows the following values:

```
#alog.log_date
Wed, 09 Feb 2011

#@dt.beginning_of_week()
Mon, 10 Oct 2011
```

Now if none of these values are nil why do I get this `undefined method >= for nil:NilClass` error on line #27. If you guys are wondering why I call this strange....its because
 1.  If I use `==` operator, everything's ok. Other operators like >, < generate the same error.
 2. This same code is working on another machine.

I don't think that it's a code problem here. Has it got something to do with the Ruby or may be Rails installation problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means precisely that `alog.log_date` is nil. `alog.log_date>=@dt.beginning_of_week()` is the same as `alog.log_date.>=(@dt.beginning_of_week())`, i.e. >= is just a method call (with some syntactic sugar). If the latter would be nil, you'd instead get something like this:

```
ArgumentError: comparison of Time with nil failed
```

You could add an existence check for the date in the beginning of the line:

```
if (alog.log_date && alog.log_date >= @dt.beginning_of_week() && alog.log_date<=@dt.end_of_week())
```

However, if you think that date should never be nil you might want to add a default value and/or a presence validation for the field.

Answer (score 1):

Good technique to catch such a bug is to attach debugger

or simplier one is to write values to log, you should just put:

`Rails.logger.info( variable_to_log )`

before  error line

PS

it works with equality operator '==' as nil object has this method

your comparison operator exists for integer class only